# Beautifulsoup remove pages numbers at bottom

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove the page numbers from this html. It seems to follow the pattern `'\n','number','\n'` if you look at the list `texts`. Would I be able to do it with BeautifulSoup? If not, how do I remove that pattern from the list?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['sup']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True

url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000156459018019254/tsla-10q_20180630.htm'
html = requests.get(url) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)

### could remove  ['\n','number','\n']

visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to extract tags containing page numbers from soup before getting text.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

for hr in soup.select('hr'):
    hr.find_previous('p').extract()

texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
```

This extracts tags with page numbers that are in style:

```
<p style="text-align:center;margin-top:12pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-size:10pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">57</p>
<p style="text-align:center;margin-top:12pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:0%;font-size:10pt;font-family:Times New Roman;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">58</p>

... etc.
```